# Ruby Unit Test : Is this a Valid (well-formed) XML Doc?

Tags: xml, ruby, unit-testing, rexml

I'm creating an XML document: I want to unit test at least to make sure it's well-formed.
So far, I have only been able to approximate this , by using the 'hasElements' in the REXML library.

Is there a better way ? 
Preferably using built-in libraries (I mean libraries that ship with the standard Ruby 1.8.x distro).

```
require "test/unit"
require 'rexml/document'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'

include REXML

class TestBasic < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def test_createXML
     my_xml=...create doc here...
     doc = Document.new(my_xml);
     assert(doc.has_elements?);
    end

end

Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(TestBasic);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[You can use Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html).
It's not a standard Ruby library, but you can easily install it as a Gem.

```
begin
  bad_doc = Nokogiri::XML(badly_formed) { |config| config.options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT }
rescue Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError => e
  puts "caught exception: #{e}"
end
# => caught exception: Premature end of data in tag root line 1
```

Comment: +1 because I prefer nokogiri over libxml too. ( Uela' Simone :) )

Comment: Thanks  - +1 - I might give this a go, but I want to avoid installing any other gems at this point !

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but it looks to be the best-fit answer here. [despite having to install another gem - but sometimes you just gotta do that!]
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I use LibXML to perform xml validations, here is the basic usage:

```
require 'libxml'

# parse DTD
dtd = LibXML::XML::Dtd.new(<<EOF)
<!ELEMENT root (item*) >
<!ELEMENT item (#PCDATA) >
EOF

# parse xml document to be validated
instance = LibXML::XML::Document.file('instance.xml')

# validate
instance.validate(dtd) # => true | false
```

from [LibXML::DTD](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html)

And this is a link to the [LibXML documentation](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html) main page.

If you don't want to use your custom validation rules you can still use a public DTD with something like:

```
require 'open-uri'
dtd =  LibXML::XML::Dtd.new(open("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd").read)
```

of course you can do much better :)

Comment: Thanks - will check that out - I actually don't have a DTD yet - but maybe I should actually write one....I'll see if it does a simple 'well-formedness' check as well.

Answer (score 0):

`rexml` - build-in library. You can use a error handler to check your xml files

```
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

errormsg = ''
doc = nil
begin
  doc = Document.new(File.new(filename))
rescue
  errormsg = $!
end

puts "Fail: #{errormsg}"   if('' != errormsg)
```